# Understanding why this question was merged and an answer deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I'm trying to work out why [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252278/1879019) I made to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234504/migrating-to-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-version-5) has been deleted.

The timeline of the question goes:

- 2019-05-21 08:47 I asked the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234504/migrating-to-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-version-5)
- 2019-05-21 08:47 A new user [claymodel answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235210/1879019) with something that didn't directly fix it.  I added a bit to the question related to that
- 2019-05-22 08:19 I finally got the code working after some trial and error and posted [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252278/1879019)
  [image]
- 2019-05-22 09:37 claymodel then posts a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253738/1879019) at  that just copies parts of my question and answer into a new answer.  This answer looks a bit rushed as it has the same code from my original question copied and pasted in at the top and bottom of the answer, wrapping the copy and paste of my answer.
  [image]
  [image]
- 2019-05-22 20:02 Jean-François Fabre [merges content from my answer into claymodel's copy and paste answer and deletes my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56253738/revisions)

The reason for the deletion in the revision history is given as 'merged multiple answers from same user', so I think what's happened here is possibly that Jean-Francois has thought that claymodel's second reply (the second set of screenshots above) was also by me, and so Jean-Francois merged them both into one (which would make complete sense).

As long as a complete and correct answer gets recorded that's the main thing, but in this case [the final answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253738/1879019) has ended up as a bit of a Frankenstein hybrid with code repeated at the top and bottom and two different author's voices.

In this case I'm not sure [claymodel's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253738/1879019) adds any real value as it just duplicates my answer and code in the original question, so I think the question would probably be more clearly answered if that answer was deleted and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252278/1879019) was reinstated.

I'm not sure what the right way to flag this up is.  Jean-Francois is a moderator, so I can't flag the question for undelete, and whilst I could flag claymodel's answer as a duplicate of mine, because mine has been deleted most users can't see my deleted response to confirm that.

I could just edit claymodel's second answer so that it makes sense and  concisely answers the question (by essentially just replacing it's content with my original answer), but that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: ah sorry for the mess. I can't reply right now (at work) but with a quick read that's what happened: double answer by someone else and overlooked the copy/pasta. Will fix this later today

Comment: Oh that's great, many thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre.  In the rare event of something like this happening am I right in thinking that there isn't a way to flag this through the normal flag procedure due to you being a mod?

Comment: yes, raise a custom flag explaining that there's been a mishap.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*I am very sorry for the mess*

Someone flagged for the same user posting two similar answers. I "merged", but failed miserably, merging your answer with the other answer, then deleted your answer... I guess I need a bigger screen ... or better eyes.

I've merged the two answers from the same author now, and undeleted your answer.

A meta question is fine, but in that case you can also raise a custom flag explaining the situation (moderators don't bite, even the ones with a puppy as an avatar :)).

If someone else checks the flag and doesn't know what to do, they'll ping the moderator who handled the flag in the moderator chatroom, and we'll resolve this.

Comment: That's great, many thanks Jean-Francois - certainly no apology needed, I've got nothing but gratitude for the work the mods do!  claymodel's second answer is weird, it's effectively just a cut and paste of the code from my question and answer, with the same code repeated once at the beginning and once at the end.  He's then copied my code into a github repo too https://github.com/claymodel/dotnetcore3/blob/master/Startup.cs .  I know it's all my code because has this really badly worded instruction "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text..." I added to remind myself what to do.

Comment: Effectively that answer is just noise, and is plagiarising the other answer. 
 I'm not sure which is the appropriate flag in that scenario?

Comment: ha! that's probably why I mixed those up. I'm not specialist in that technology (as everyone could see :)). I'll check with the other mods.

Answer (score -5):

In this case of I would rather appretiate removing my answers and github contribution. Please accept the original answer rather than mine.
Thanks.

Comment: you give question and give answer. there is no pasta plagiarism is there aslong as some effort in answering also giving a full set of runable example from github. its out of nothing to discourage answering. thats why I have removed my answer but at the same time would appretiate such comments like plagiarism or so.

Comment: also I saw entry in issues in my repo. if you are an original c# coder should have observed the whole project and way of writing. if this is plagiarism then all dotnet c# cli plugin codes are. you want to get reward points in your own question using own aswer, that is ok. but it is social platform and there must be respect on other contributors as well. any way this is an exceptional case seen in this site!